# debootstrap chroot x11 cannot open display 0 no protocol error

Tags: linux, x11, chroot, display, debootstrap

after installing a chroot, I found trouble when connecting to x11, I would think this was a normal use case but coudln't find anything specific about this use case

```
# debootstrap stable /srv/stable/
...
# chroot /srv/stable/ xeyes
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

Answer (score 3):

First, x11 clients need to talk to the x11 server via a socket file, usually 
`/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`

```
# mount -o bind /tmp/ /srv/stable/tmp/
```

Second, <strike>`xauth`</strike> I mean, `xhost` which I keep confusing together.

> either A, (Recomended) the uid of the process inside the chroot must
>   match the uid of the user who owns the xauthority on the host, for
>   example we can clone the username/groupname userid/groupid of the host
>   user to the chroot (usually uid/gid 1000/1000)
>
> ```
> # chroot /srv/stable groupadd -g $(id -g) $(id -gn)
> # chroot /srv/stable useradd -u $(id -u) -g $(id -g) $(id -un)
> ```

.

> or B, the uid of the process in the chroot must otherwise be
>   authorized, in the xauthority file, for example; chroot will run as
>   uid 0 inside the chroot, so we can authorize uid 0 outside the chroot
>   like so:
>
> ```
> # xhost +si:localhost:root
> localhost:root being added to access control list
> ```

our graphical programs should have connectivity and authority to use the x11 display now:

```
# chroot /srv/stable sudo -u $(id -un) xeyes
# chroot /srv/stable xeyes
```

Comment: `X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)`